# Using Symfony 2 Components in Magento

Tags: magento, symfony

How easy would it be to integrate some Symfony 2 components/bundles to the Magento framework?

I am thinking in particular the twig templating engine, though the question will generally apply to any components?

Comment: It would have a difficulty of 8.7.

Comment: Ok - get your point :) I suppose, im really asking is it feesable.

Comment: Magento is using Zend Framework so you'll have to rewrite a large part of your code i think

Answer (score 0):

using the twig template engine in any php project is quiet easy because it's a standalone component that is not tied to symfony.

to empower you projects with twig requires the following three simple steps:

first you need to get the code, as described [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#installation), then you need to initialize the autoloading and the template engine:

```
// setup autoloader
require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// initialize template engine
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));
```

then you can use it anywhere in your project to render templates:

```
// load a template
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');

// render the template
echo $template->render(array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
```

as for other parts of symfony, the components can also easily integrated in other projects as they are meant for that, have a look on the [components page](http://symfony.com/components).

using bundles is a bit more complicated because they are tied to the symfony core and need a fully bootstrapped instance of symfony which is a little overhead but also no problem. take a look on my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961808/how-can-i-access-symfony2-services-from-an-external-legacy-system/10989002#10989002) question which is about accessing symfony functionality from a legacy app.

Answer (score 0):

Using twig in general is very easy.
You need to create an own Block which overwrites some of the block methods defined in Mage_Core_Block_Template
Or you go a level deeper and extend directly Mage_Core_Block_Abstract to write an own _toHtml() method.

I dont know which functions twig offers by default, but some of the Symfony ones could be a little harder to implement.

The biggest problem will be to register the autoloader, as you need to workaround a limitation of magento for this. But there exist a common solution where you unregister the autoloader and after registering your autoloader you reregister the magento one. How you solve this is your decision, but after the magento autoloader is executed, no other has a chance for autoloading. Also I am not sure about the security problems caused by a different autoloader, as magento handles the module and controller autoloading separate.

At all sure not more than 50-60 lines of code, but you need to know a bit about magento to implement it properly.